# How do i extract "date" from this specific website using BeautifulSoup4 in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, date, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I want to extract

> DATE not data

from the below given link:

```
http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/iit-bombay-birds-eye-view-and-quantum-biology/article18191268.ece
```

Using BeautifulSoup4 in python 2.7.I want the output to look like:

```
April 22, 2017 18:57 IST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/iit-bombay-birds-eye-view-and-quantum-biology/article18191268.ece'
)
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

ut_container = soup.find("div", {"class": "ut-container"})
time = ut_container.find("none").text.strip()
print(time)
```

But IMO you have to be prepared - when working with bs4 -  to play with it, to look for html selectors, to search documentation, and to be patient.

I hope that it wasn't your laziness ;)